# Shuffling numbers in bash using seed

Tags: bash, random, gnu-coreutils

I want to create an array of integers, where the numbers are from 1...N. Each number appears once in this array. For instance array = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4} when N = 5.

In order to produce this array, I use the shuffle method as:

```
        array=($(shuf -i 1-$N -n $N ))
```

It works fine. However, I want to add seed to this code to make sure every time I run the code with the same seed, I get the same array. Is it possible to do that using the shuffle method?

Comment: Which specific implementation of `shuf`?

Comment: BTW, that's not actually a good-practice way to read into an array; consider `readarray` or `mapfile` if on bash 4.0 or newer, or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(shuf -i "1-$N" -n "$N" && printf '\0')` for support for bash 3.x -- that way you aren't relying on string-splitting (and thus dependent on the current value of IFS, and inadvertently running glob expansion).

Comment: Anyhow. If it's GNU `shuf` (which we can't tell, because `shuf` isn't part of bash but is a separately-shipped tool), then `--random-source` will do.

Comment: (Hmm. Annoying -- we had a duplicate question within the last week, but the OP deleted it when they found out `--random-source` existed, so it's not available to link to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU implementation of `shuf` has a `--random-source` argument. Passing this argument with the name of a file with known contents will result in a reliable set of output.

See the [Random sources](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html#Random-sources) documentation in the GNU coreutils manual, which contains the following sample implementation:

> ```
> get_seeded_random()
> {
>   seed="$1"
>   openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$seed" -nosalt \
>     </dev/zero 2>/dev/null
> }
>
> shuf -i1-100 --random-source=<(get_seeded_random 42)
> ```

To load a result into a bash array in a manner that doesn't rely on string-splitting (and thus the current value of IFS), your implementation may instead look like:

```
# with bash 4.0 or newer
readarray -t array < <(shuf -i1-100 --random-source=<(get_seeded_random 42))

# or, supporting bash 3.x as well
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array \
  < <(shuf -i1-100 --random-source=<(get_seeded_random 42) && printf '\0')
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using bash 4.3 and it works perfectly fine. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In bash alone (without using external tools like `shuf` or `openssl`, you can use `$RANDOM` which you can seed with pseudo-random input like so:

```
RANDOM=$$
```

or

```
RANDOM=$(date '+%s')
```

etc.

And you can select a range of numbers using expressions like `{1..N}`.

```
declare -a a=()
for n in {1..5}; do
    a[$RANDOM]=$n
done
echo "${a[@]}"
```

This solution as coded above has a non-zero risk of failure in case of repeated random values, which could be mitigated through some extra code, or reduced by extending the random range, for example using bit-shifting to make a 30-bit unsigned integer instead of a 15 bit unsigned integer:

```
...
    a[$(( (RANDOM<<15)+RANDOM ))]=$n
...
```

The output with this solution is "randomized" because in bash, elements of a non-associative array are naturally ordered numerically by the value of their index.

Note that "sequential" is also a valid random order.  :-)

```
$ a=(); for n in {1..5}; do a[$RANDOM]=$n; done; declare -p a
declare -a a=([7460]="5" [12697]="3" [16841]="2" [21485]="1" [32493]="4")
$ a=(); for n in {1..5}; do a[$RANDOM]=$n; done; declare -p a
declare -a a=([1444]="1" [12162]="2" [17774]="3" [29827]="4" [31840]="5")
```